# Finding a complex function satisfying a relation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a complex differentiable function. Suppose $f$ satisfies
$$f(e^{i\frac{2\pi }{n}}t)=\frac{1}{f(t)}$$
where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (a variable) and $n$ is some natural number. Does such a function exist, and if so, what are some examples (besides the trivial ones)?
This is related to some independent work I'm doing on contour integration. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Constant function equal to 1 clearly works. Not sure if this is the only one, but I wouldn’t be surprised if it is.

Comment: It seems $t$ is allowed to vary; what about $n$?

Comment: By Euler's identity:

$f \left( e^{i \frac{2 \pi t}{n}} \right) = f \left[ \cos \left( \dfrac{2 \pi t}{n} \right) + i \sin \left( \dfrac{2 \pi t}{n} \right) \right] = \dfrac{1}{f(t)}$

Comment: What about $$f(z)=\frac{e^{i\pi\frac{n-1}{n}}}{t^2}z$$?

Comment: If it should hold for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $f$ needs to be constant by the identity theorem and therefore the only possibilities would be $f\equiv \pm 1.$

Comment: @GregMartin t is a variable, and n is some natural number

Comment: So, does this mean that $f(e^{2\pi i/n}t)=1/f(t)$ holds for *all* $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and for *some* $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then the functional equation leads to $f(z)=1/f(z)$, and so, $f(z)=\pm 1$. If $n$ is even, then functions of the form $f(z)=\pm \exp(c z^{n/2})$ work.